# JavaScript. Absolute position of <li> element relative to browser bounds?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to know the absolute position of `<li>` element relative to browser bounds?

```
<html>
    <body style="overflow: hidden">
        <div ID="Ticker" style="position:absolute; white-space: nowrap;">
            <ol style="list-style-type:decimal; ">
                <li style="float: left; width: 100px; padding: 2px 0px;">Test</li>
                <li style="float: left; width: 100px; padding: 2px 0px;">Test</li>
                <li ID="TargetElem" style="float: left; width: 100px; padding: 2px 0px;">Test</li>
                <li style="float: left; width: 100px; padding: 2px 0px;">Test</li>
                <li style="float: left; width: 100px; padding: 2px 0px;">Test</li>
                <li style="float: left; width: 100px; padding: 2px 0px;">Test</li>
                <li style="float: left; width: 100px; padding: 2px 0px;">Test</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ticker.js" language="javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need a way to know the left value of element `<li>` with `ID="TargetElem"`.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are not related, so I've retagged your post to remove the `[java]` tag.

Answer (score 5):

Borrowed from http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html...

```
// findPosition() by quirksmode.org
// Finds the **absolute** position of an element on a page
function findPosition(obj) {

   var curleft = curtop = 0;
   if (obj.offsetParent) {
      do {

         /*
          * The loop continues until the object currently being investigated 
          * does not have an offsetParent any more. While the offsetParent is 
          * still there, it still adds the offsetLeft of the object to curleft, 
          * and the offsetTop to curtop.
          */
         curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
         curtop += obj.offsetTop;

      } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
   }

   return [curleft,curtop];
}
```

This function *should* work well in IE6, IE7, IE8, Safari, Firefox and Chrome but I haven't tested it thoroughly. Also, this article might be relevant for your needs...

- http://blog.stannard.net.au/2010/05/22/find-the-position-of-an-element-with-javascript/

I hope this helps.

Comment: +1. Until I saw your message, I was going to post the same code (I've once found that webpage, when I had a similar problem).

Comment: Thanks :) I'm sure there are multiple ways of doing this, perhaps better ways of doing it as well. For example, I'm not sure if `offsetParent` is supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Plain JS:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('TargetElem');
var left = elem.offsetLeft;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jFVGc/1/).

---

jQuery offers the following option:

The [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/) of the element gives the position of the top-left corner of the element in terms of its distance, in pixels, from the top-left corner of the window.

To find the x-offset of the element:

```
$('#TargetElem').offset().left
```

To find the y-offset of the element:

```
$('#TargetElem').offset().top
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jFVGc/).

Comment: This is jQuery. Nowhere in the post does he mention jQuery.

Comment: @Chris, thanks! Although originally the jQuery suggestion was my entire answer (and, as @Ryan correctly noted, was not requested in the question) *sigh* =)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. I thought @Ryan's comment was a little weird until I looked in the post history.

Comment: @Chris +1 (for taking the time to look) =)

Answer (score 0):

```
var elem = document.getElementById('TargetElem'),
    left = elem.offsetLeft;
```

Assuming the <li> is offset relative to the window, this will give you the correct value.